# Пожалуйста подскажите с ползунком?

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

Ребята подскажите пожалуйста, что не так, если я ввожу для min значение больше max то ползунок не пересекает min отметку, не пойму почему когда я ввожу для max значение меньше минимального либо больше у меня ползунок возвращается к начальному значению, а не остается рядом с минимальным или на значении которое я ввел.

```js
$("#rangeslider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  values: [35, 62],
  range: true,
  create: function(event, ui) {
    $("#rangeMin").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 0));
    $("#rangeMax").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 1));
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $("#rangeMin").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 0));
    $("#rangeMax").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 1));
  },
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#rangeMin").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 0));
    $("#rangeMax").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 1));
  }
});

$("#rangeMin").keyup(function(event, ui) {
  var valueMin = $("#rangeMin").val();
  var valueMax = $("#rangeMax").val();

  if (parseInt(valueMin) > parseInt(valueMax)) {
    valueMin = valueMax;
    $("#rangeMin").val(valueMin);
  }
  $("#rangeslider").slider("values", 0, valueMin);
});

$("#rangeMax").keyup(function(event, ui) {
  var valueMin = $("#rangeMin").val();
  var valueMax = $("#rangeMax").val();

  if (valueMax > 100) {
    valueMax = 100;
    $("#rangeMax").val(100)
  }

  if (parseInt(valueMin) > parseInt(valueMax)) {
    valueMax = valueMin;
    $("#rangeMax").val(valueMax);
  }
  $("#rangeslider").slider("values", 1, valueMax);
});
```

```css
#rangeslider {
  width: 200px;
}

#rangeMin {
  width: 30px;
}

#rangeMax {
  width: 30px;
}

.ui-slider {
  position: relative;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: url(../img/slider.png) no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: .7em;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
  height: 3px;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
  top: -5px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
  left: 0;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max {
  right: 0;
}

.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ui-widget-header {
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="rangeslider">
  <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <span>Mim</span>
  <input id="rangeMin" value="0" type="text">
  </span>
  <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <span>Max</span>
  <input id="rangeMax" value="100" type="text">
  </span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: вижу событие на передвижение ползунка -
 `$('#rangeslider').change`, а где событие на изменение инпутов?

Comment: честно говоря я в этом не силен, вот  $('#rangeslider').change(function(e) {
    switch (this.id) {
      case "rangeMin":
      case "rangeMax":
        var index = (this.id == "rangeMax") ? 1 : 0;
        $('#rangeslider').slider("values", index, $(this).val())
        break;
    }
  }) я не правильно записал

Comment: он без этого работает, только не передвигается

Comment: Да у тебя и значение не вводится...

Comment: помогите если не трудно

Answer (score 1):

Подскажите, что сейчас не так, если я ввожу значение больше максимального, то ползунок не пересекает максимальную отметку; почему, когда я ввожу для макс значение меньше минимального, у меня ползунок возвращается к начальному значению, а не остается рядом с минимальным?

```js
$("#rangeslider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  values: [35, 62],
  range: true,
  create: function(event, ui) {
    $("#rangeMin").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 0));
    $("#rangeMax").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 1));
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $("#rangeMin").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 0));
    $("#rangeMax").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 1));
  },
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#rangeMin").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 0));
    $("#rangeMax").val($("#rangeslider").slider("values", 1));
  }
});

$("#rangeMin").keyup(function(event, ui) {
  var valueMin = $("#rangeMin").val();
  var valueMax = $("#rangeMax").val();

  if (parseInt(valueMin) > parseInt(valueMax)) {
    valueMin = valueMax;
    $("#rangeMin").val(valueMin);
  }
  $("#rangeslider").slider("values", 0, valueMin);
});

$("#rangeMax").keyup(function(event, ui) {
  var valueMin = $("#rangeMin").val();
  var valueMax = $("#rangeMax").val();

  if (valueMax > 100) {
    valueMax = 100;
    $("#rangeMax").val(100)
  }

  if (parseInt(valueMin) > parseInt(valueMax)) {
    valueMax = valueMin;
    $("#rangeMax").val(valueMax);
  }
  $("#rangeslider").slider("values", 1, valueMax);
});
```

```css
#rangeslider {
 width: 200px;
}

#rangeMin {
width: 30px;
}

#rangeMax {
width: 30px;
}

.ui-slider {
 position: relative;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 13px; 
 height: 13px; 
 background: url(../img/slider.png) no-repeat; 
 cursor: pointer
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 font-size: .7em;
 display: block;
 border: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
  height: 3px; 
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle { 
 top: -5px;
 margin-left: -6px;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range {
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min { 
 left: 0;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max {
 right: 0;
}
.ui-widget-content { 
 border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ui-widget-header { 
 border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
 background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="rangeslider">
  <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <span>Mim</span>
  <input id="rangeMin" value="0" type="text">
  </span>
  <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <span>Max</span>
  <input id="rangeMax" value="100" type="text">
  </span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: 1. Стрелочки не работают. 2. Max может быть меньше чем min. 3. Рамка при перетаскивании выглядит ужасно.

Comment: 1. При фокусе на ползунок стрелочки работают. 2. Вопрос был в том, чтобы при изменении значения инпута передвигался ползунок. 3. Суть ведь в том, чтобы работало, а не было красиво, в данной ситуации.

Comment: @nimble в данный момент, всё работает корректно. минимальное значение не залезает за максимальное и наоборот

Comment: @fanfer если на максимальном ползунке ввести число которое  больше минимального, то ползунок не становится в нужно место, а возвращается на отметку 100